# About a property of bounded closed convex set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Terminology:**
>
> - For a bounded closed convex (bcc for short) set $A$, define $w(A)$ to be the infimum of the distance between pairs of
>     parallel hyperplanes supporting $A$.
> - We say that a bcc set $A$ is *reduced*, if for every bcc set
>     $A'$ strictly contained in $A$, we have $w(A') < w(A)$.
> - We say that a bcc set $A$ is *diametrically minimal*, if
>     every bcc set $A'$ strictly contained in $A$ has a smaller diameter.
> - A set is *of constant width* means the distance between
>     two supporting hyperplanes is the same, in any direction.
>
> **Question:** Is it true that every reduced diametrically minimal bcc set is of constant width?

Comment: What does "row reduced" mean in this context?

Comment: It's reduced not row reduced.

Comment: If the ambient space (I assume Banach by your tag) is not reflexive, then continuous linear functionals need not assume their sup on $A$ ([James' theorem](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=170192)). So it is unclear what you mean by supporting hyperplanes "in any direction".